# Reading xml from url using js

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

I was trying to read xml data provided by the url

url: http://api.simplyhired.co.in/a/jobs-api/xml-v2/q-java/l-hyderabad/ws-10?pshid=46408&ssty=3&cflg=r

but I am not getting any response data from the url. I tried below code:

```
var url = "http://api.simplyhired.co.in/a/jobs-api/xml-v2/q-java/l-hyderabad/ws-10?pshid=46408&ssty=3&cflg=r";

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    complete: function(data) {
        alert(data.responseText);
    }
});​
```

When I open url in the browser it shows data in xml format. The problem exists even after encoding the url.

Is there any better way of doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
    url: "www.mysite.com/file.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
       #do work here if success
    }
});
```

if this still not work, pay attention at your url, it have some chars that should be encoded (e.g. "=" that encoded is a "%3D")

see here for JQuery URI encoding: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURIComponent.asp

Comment: my url does not end with .xml

Comment: what you receive as response? a html error (404, 500,...) or something like an empty xml?

Comment: again, try to put the var url directly in the jquery code and assign them another name that "url" (e.g. xmlUrl), maybe can cause mismatch with the line "url: url"